# Calculating heights of bookings in calendar weekview

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, calendar, resize

I'm building a calendar that should give an abstract visualization of the hours that you've booked in that week. So every .bar-item means x minutes spend on something. Now i'm struggling a bit finding a way to make sure the days stay in proportion to each other.

What i did is i take the longest day in the week and the height of the container the bars are in. This way i can calculate what how high(px) 1 minute is on the longest day, and use this value for all the days. I hope this makes sense.

I made this fiddle with some hard coded data: https://jsfiddle.net/luffyyyyy/vate1d4h/13/

```
new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            minuteHeight: 0,
            longestDay: 600
        },
        mounted() {
            window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
            this.handleResize();
        },
        destroyed() {
            window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
        },
        methods: {
            handleResize() {
                this.minuteHeight = this.$refs.container.offsetHeight / this.longestDay;
                console.log(this.minuteHeight);
            }
        }
    });
```

Now this works when you load the page, and this works when you make te page bigger (it scales). But when u start making the page smaller it stays at the biggest size (i think?).

1. Is this the correct way to go about this?
2. Why doesn't it scale down when making the browser smaller?

Comment: Looks like it works fine for me. Can you add a screenshot of the behaviour you're experiencing and your expected behaviour?

Comment: If you inspect the .bar-items you can see the inline-style (height) i'm calculating changing when you make the browser bigger, when you try to size it back down (make the browser smaller) nothing happens which results in a scrollbar. All bookings should be visible 100% of the time so they should scale down when i make the browser smaller.

Comment: Ah wait, you meant vertical resizing. I have the same issue you're having, let me check if I can find an answer for you...

Comment: The height of your container is defined by the total height of all bar-items. Those in turn get set by the minuteHeight property, and that gets set by the container height. This loop makes sure that the numbers can only get bigger (by resizing), but never get smaller. Try calculating the minuteHeight on something like the window (like @ chr suggests), so this recurring loop breaks and your application behaves as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend having a fixed height for the `longestDay`, in other words, you could say 1 minute has a `height` of `2px`. This way, your calculation gets much easier, assuming you have enough vertical space. In your code example 1 minutes is `0.396px` on a smaller viewport.

If you want to label the bookings, you need to consider the case, if a booking is too small.

Edit: I fixed the resize issue by changing the calculation of your `handleResize` method. Currently the container height is used for the calculation. When increasing the window height, the container is expanding according to your css rules. When shrinking the window height, a scroll bar is appearing because the container height is not changing. You have to use the interior height of the window for your calculation.

```
handleResize() {
    this.minuteHeight = window.innerHeight / this.longestDay;
}
```

Comment: Ty, this is working indeed! The only problem i have with this is that i have to do something like this when working with the window size instead of the container size:

                    var height = window.innerHeight - 280;
                    this.minuteHeight = height / this.longestDay; This to make sure i have some white space underneath the bars: https://jsfiddle.net/luffyyyyy/vate1d4h/16/ . So the 280 is the height of all other components in my layout combined, when a height changes or something is added i have to change my javascript.